# rails migration copy and remove table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have user model and user model has_one profile model.
Also I have user.phone and user.profile.phone but I want to remove user.phone and I will use only user.profile.phone.

Before I remove the user.phone,I wanna copy user.phone to user.profile.phone if user.phone is not blank.Then I will remove user.phone

For instance:

```
user.phone = 123
user.profile.phone = 234
```

After migration:

```
user.phone will be removed
user.profile.phone = 123 - 234
```

What is the appropriate migration for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
   User.find_each do |user|
 user.profile.update_attributes(:phone => user.phone) unless user.phone.blank?
   end
   remove_column :users, :phone
 end

 def self.down
  add_column :users, :phone, :string
 end
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Model.all.each do...` in a migration like that. It'll load all 5-freaking-million rows into memory at once. Instead use `Model.find_each do...` , which loads the rows 1000 at a time. It didn't exist when this answer was first posted.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is not very large you can simply do like this:

```
User.includes(:profile).all.each{ |u| u.profile.phone = u.phone unless u.phone.nil? }
```

in your console. Or you can write smth like this in your migration:

```
def change
  User.includes(:profile).all.each{ |u| u.profile.phone = u.phone unless u.phone.nil? }
  remove_column :users, :phone
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
     User.where("phone IS NOT NULL").includes(:profiles).each{ |u| u.profile.phone = u.phone}
     remove_column :users, :phone
  end
  def self.down
    add_column :users, :phone, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to use Model in migration because it creates unnecessary pain:

Assume many people working on same project and you use model in migration do commit. Other person delete the user model or applies some validation on model and dos the commit. When he or other tries to run the migrations, it may fail because the model you used is not exists or some validation.

So I recommend to use SQL statements in migration.

```
class SomeMigartion < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute('update profiles p inner join users u on p.user_id = u.id set p.phone = u.phone where u.phone is not null')
    remove_column :users, :phone
  end

  def self.down
     add_coulmn :users, :phone
  end
end
```